# extending default nginx mime.types file

Tags: nginx, mime-types

I'd like to add a few extra types to nginx mime types, but I don't want to edit the default  `/etc/nginx/mime.types` as it would add some extra complexity to the deployment process.

If I add a [`types {...}`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types) section to my `nginx.conf` it will override all the other types that were declared with the `include mime.types;`.

I've thought that I could write a location rule for the extensions of the files that I need to handle, but I suppose that there must be a cleaner way to achieve this.

Answer (score 91):

> If I add a types {...} section to my nginx.conf it will override all
>   the other types that were declared with the include mime.types;.

No, it won't.

You just need to specify additional types on the same level as your `mime.types` include:

```
include mime.types;
types {
    # here are additional types
    application/javascript mjs;
}
```

Comment: only if the include and types are in the same `scope`

Comment: it works with the "include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;" instead of "include mime.types;" and adding of course the extra types "types {
    # here are additional types
    application/javascript mjs;
}"