# Correct image/svg+xml validation

Tags: xml, svg

I'm building a svg map and when I try to validate on W3C it gives me two warnings. Can anyone help me how to fix theses warnings.? Thanks

```
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg  viewBox="0 0 1000 2112" style="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

    <path ...> </path>
</svg>
```

**1. Missing "charset" attribute for "text/xml" document.**

The HTTP Content-Type header (text/xml) sent by your web browser (Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0) did not contain a "charset" parameter, but the Content-Type was one of the XML text/* sub-types.

The relevant specification (RFC 3023) specifies a strong default of "us-ascii" for such documents so we will use this value regardless of any encoding you may have indicated elsewhere.

If you would like to use a different encoding, you should arrange to have your browser send this new encoding information.

**2. Warning Conflict between Mime Type and Document Type**

The document is being served with the text/xml Mime Type which is not a registered media type for the Document Type. The recommended media type for this document is: image/svg+xml

Using a wrong media type for a certain document type may confuse the validator and other user agents with respect to the nature of the document, and you may get some erroneous validation errors. How to fix this problem? One of the following techniques should help:

```
If you are serving a static file on a Web server, changing its extension should help. Use e.g .xhtml for XHTML or .mml for MathML.
You may need to reconfigure your Web server. This Setting up MIME Types tutorial has instructions for Apache, Tomcat and IIS.
If the document is generated dynamically, the scripting language should allow you to set up the mime type: this article on MIME Types and Content Negotiation has examples in PHP, Perl, and ASP.
```

Comment: The message already tells you what is _wrong_ – so what have you done so far in trying to _fix_ it? Any prior research on your part worth mentioning? With what results?

Comment: Your web server is missing this mime type `image/svg+xml` info. Either send the correct mime header or add it in the server's config file. Apache uses [mod_mime](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html) while nginx uses a [default file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789494/extending-default-nginx-mime-types-file)