# Using TTF files for font-family

Tags: html, css

I am trying to use a .ttf file downloaded from web to use 'anagram.ttf' as my font-family.

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    @font-face {font-family: 'Anagram'; src: url('anagram.ttf');}
    p{font-family:anagram;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is paragraph one.</p>
    <p>This is paragraph two.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

But, finally my browser is showing as:

```
Rendered fonts: Times New Roman—22 glyphs
```

Also showing warning in console:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: file:///C:/codebook/external%20fonts/anagram.ttf
```

Is my syntax wrong or any other problem?

Comment: Is your URL path is correct?

Comment: yes .... it is corect.

Comment: is your font file is in same file where there is html

Comment: just check this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442319/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font

Comment: this error only occurs when the font decoded is not loaded means the url is mistake

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please make this changes to your code so that it can understand what type of file format it is.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Anagram';
  src: url('anagram.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is not wrong. Make sure your file is correct wherever you downloaded from.

Comment: Tell me from where have you downloaded anagram.ttf?

Answer (score 2):

Do like this or there may be some error while referencing the font..

Or there may be the `url` issue..

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Anagram';
    src: url('anagram.ttf') format('truetype');
}

div {
    font-family: Anagram;
}
```

Comment: http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/tag/heavy - I downloaded 'anagram.ttf'  from here ... see it