# Laravel elixir: how it works

Tags: laravel, laravel-elixir

Its always nice to use Laravel elixir feature. But I have some basic question. Firstly
when we run gulp command, it concatenates all the css and js files. But I think I dont need, for example, datatables.css and datatables.js/boostrap-wysihtml for all of my pages. how to tackle this situation?

Secondly Lets review this code:

```
elixir(function(mix) {

    mix.styles([
      "bootstrap.min.css",
      "owl.carousel.css",
      "animate.css",
      "style.css",
      "datepicker.css"
    ]);

    mix.scripts([
      "jquery.min.js",
      "bootstrap.min.js",
      "bootstrap-datepicker.js",
      "typed.min.js",
      "wow.min.js",
      "owl.carousel.min.js",
      "home.js",
      "side-navigation.js",
      "script.js"
    ]);

    mix.version(["css/all.css","js/all.js"]);
});
```

in blade:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url(elixir('css/all.css')) }}">
```

what is the use of this elixir() function, when we are creating all.js and all.css file that has everything concatenated inside it?

Comment: I have answered a very similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35135525/elixir-gulp-laravel-with-differents-js-inclusions-depending-on-url/35136313#35136313) which if you read, might help show you the answer to your question about including only what is needed in your `elixir` files.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the elixir function in the blade template because it will automatically use the rev.manifest file to resolve which versioned file(s) to use. The [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/elixir#versioning-and-cache-busting) have more info. As far as not needing all scripts on all pages, there are a few different ways to pull it off. You can create a task that generates just generates one bundle - perhaps scripts needed everywhere - and another bundle handling the rest. I'd advise you to research that to see what works best for you.