# Keep getting "Failed to decode downloaded font" despite correct URL

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, fonts

I checked all of SO, but wasn't able to figure out what's wrong in my specific case.

Here's my CSS:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(/assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

But Chrome keeps throwing a `Failed to decode downloaded font` and `OTS parsing error: DSIG: invalid table offset` error in the console. As a result, the fonts are not being applied on the elements properly. The URL to the fonts are definitely correct, so I am not sure what's going wrong here.

This is only happening in Chrome. It works fine in Safari.

Comment: Can you change `url(/assets/..` to `url(../assets/..`.Also i think the url needs quotes

Comment: [**Google Might Help**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=OTS+parsing+error%3A+DSIG%3A+invalid+table+offset&oq=OTS+parsing+error%3A+DSIG%3A+invalid+table+offset&aqs=chrome..69i57.719j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: @Mihai I tried changing it, but the warnings are still coming up.

Comment: "All of SO"... yea right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to decode downloaded font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442319/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font)

Comment: Funny how the "Google might help" link someone posted above points right back to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your url attribute should lose the first `/` so it will look like this - just to try and troubleshoot, give that a shot.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: local('Open Sans Light'), local('OpenSans-Light'), url(assets/fonts/OpenSans-Light.ttf) format('truetype');
}
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url(assets/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Also for the sake of troubleshooting try linking directly from the Google Fonts site - if that works it will give clues to other issues.