# Font-awesome error during upgrade from grails 2.x to grails 3.x

Tags: css, grails, fonts

I am trying to upgrade grails project from 2.x.x to 3.1.8 and my font-awesome is not resolved. I downloaded font-awesome zip from internet and put fonts to file to /assets/fonts and than I put font-awesome.css to my css.

I also added added:

grails.resources.adhoc.patterns = ['/images/*', '/css/*', '/js/*', '/plugins/*', '/fonts/*']
grails.resources.adhoc.includes = ['/images/**', '/css/**', '/js/**', '/plugins/**', '/fonts/**']
to my application.groovy.

Here is my error:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:8080/dist/tjicons.ttf?bf6f8c5837e0c76e84bd8c564a18c8e5(index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
```

Any ideas?

PS: Resource plugin was used in grails 2.

---

EDIT:

Font-awesome.css:

```
@font-face {font-family: 'FontAwesome';src: url('../fonts/fontawesomewebfont.eot?v=4.6.3');
src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.6.3') format('embedded-opentype'), 
url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.6.3') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.6.3') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.6.3') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.6.3#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');font-weight: normal;font-style: normal;
```

application.css:

```
*= require_self
*= require bootstrap
*= require font-awesome
*= require_tree .
```

Comment: Can you show us the code on your css where is calling the fonts? Maybe In the css rule you have to add the extension of the file.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31142570/2166188

Comment: I think I have this mapped correctly. Idea doesnt show any errors either.

Comment: Error is linked with **tjicons.ttf** not **fontawesome-webfont.ttf**.

Comment: Yes you are right Michal Szulc. I have also just found out. I got a new project and thought that these icons are part of font-awesome. Thank you guys anyway. Topic Closed