# Self hosting Google's Material Design Icon Fonts - OTS parsing error - Invalid Version tag

Tags: html, css, material-design, font-face, icon-fonts

I want to self host Material Design Icon Fonts. I have followed their [developer guide](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-2-self-hosting). So I downloaded the icon font [from here](https://github.com/google/material-design-icons/tree/master/iconfont), coppied the `eot`, `ttf`, `woff` and `woff2` files into my project directory and included it in my CSS. But I am getting a ton of errors:

[image]

The question is why and how do I fix it. SSCCE follows:

```css
/* fallback */

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('fonts/material/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot');
  /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'), local('MaterialIcons-Regular'), url('fonts/material/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2') format('woff2'), url('fonts/material/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff') format('woff'), url('fonts/material/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf') format('truetype');
}
.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;
  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="material.min.css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="material.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button"><i class="material-icons">chevron_left</i>
  </button>
</body>

</html>
```

**The question is why and how to fix this?**

*My Project Hierarchy:*

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Failed to decode downloaded font](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442319/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font)

Answer (score 0):

use this format:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Pretty Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

Comment: What part of that is going to help, and how is it different from mine?

Answer (score 0):

If you downloaded the fonts from the webbrowser via "save link" you might download an incomplete ASCII version instead of binary. I run into this problem too and found a solution from Jodamo5 [here](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/custom-fonts-returns-failed-to-decode-downloaded-font/) 
Ps, if you are not using FTP you can also download the complete master.zip file from your browser and extract the required font files from the zip.