# Failed to decode downloaded font create-react-app with base64 encoded font

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm getting a warning:

> Failed to decode downloaded font:
>   data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAAAAABIYAA0AAAAAG5gAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABGRlRNAAAR/AAAABoAAAAcgngKt0dERUYAABHgAAAAHAAAAB4AJwAYT1MvMgAAAZgAAABCAAAAYA8yHPpjbWFwAAACGAAAAIoAAAHGpyaHlWdhc3AAABHYAAAACAAAAAgAAAAQZ2x5ZgAAAswAAA3QAAAVCGGGcXVoZWFkAAABMAAAAC4AAAA2FTIoLGhoZWEAAAFgAAAAIAAAACQNAwkTaG10eAAAAdwAAAA8AAAARja6AU9sb2NhAAACpAAAACYAAAAmI4odrG1heHAAAAGAAAAAGAAAACAAGwGbbmFtZQAAEJwAAADcAAABm/pYTdhwb3N0AAAReAAAAF4AAAC9IEs0anjaY2BkAANfW9Z18fw2Xxm4WcD8a5kfr8Po/3/+7+d0YT4E5HIwMIFEAVg...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

When trying to load a base64 encoded custom font.

I'm using an ejected create-react-app.

Thus far I have tried adding format('woff') to my `src` property as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442319/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41676054/how-to-add-fonts-to-create-react-app-based-projects)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'custom-icon_map';
  src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,blahBLAHblah) format('woff');
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

This will suppress the warnings, however my issue is still not fixed as my icons will not load locally.  However, when the application is deployed to production the icons load fine.

Any thoughts?