# How to fix Failed to decode downloaded font while using CDN version of google fonts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-fonts

I am having an issue using `Mali` font with light version ie `font-weight: 300;` while using a CDN version of google font.

> Failed to decode downloaded font: https://fonts.gstatic.com/stats/Mali/normal/300

I am using the font like this:

```
<link
 rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Mali:300" 
 type="text/css">
```

So, before filing a bug to google fonts, I want to confirm if there is any solution.

Basically, I want to try overriding the format value:

```
@font-face {
  src: url(...) format('embeded-open')
```

But not aware if we can just override the format leaving url intact.

I tried overriding like the following, but din't work:

```
@font-face {
  src: format('embeded-open');
}
```

### **Ouch, @font-face rule can't be overridden.**

<kbd>javascript</kbd>, <kbd>jquery</kbd>

Also, if there is any way to know if there is warning error occurred, then do something - with this particular case, I would be glad to..

PS: I have looked all solutions provided in [the post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442319/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font). But not able to fix this issue.