# How can I get my downloaded Google font to work in my React Project?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-fonts

I downloaded a google font and want to use it in my project...

I added this CSS code

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Work Sans";
  src: local("Work Sans"),
    url(../src/Fonts/Work_Sans/WorkSans-VariableFont_wght.ttf) format("truetype");
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/src/Fonts/Work_Sans/static/WorkSans-Regular.ttf
localhost/:1 OTS parsing error: invalid sfntVersion: 1008813135
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: That "sfntVersion: 1008813135" shows that you are passing HTML data  instead of font data to a font parser. `sfntVersion`are the first four bytes in a font file, and `1008813134` is `0x3c21444f` in hex and `<!DO` in ASCII, so it is most probably the beginning of `<!DOCTYPE`. This means that the server returns an HTML string instead of a font file, maybe due to a bad URL.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure how to use downloaded google fonts but you could also just import it through your HTML `<Head>`  section of your `index.html`.

Here is the code you'd need to put inside the head of your index.html

```
link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@300&family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;1,100&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or you can choose your own styles and

1. [go here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Work+Sans?query=work%20sans#styles)
2. scroll down to where it shows you the different **styles**
3. press the + button of the styles you want
4. hit the top right button that says "view selected families"
5. copy and paste the automatically generated code into `<Head>` inside of index.html

This is how you'd apply it inside of your CSS:

```
font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
```

Comment: Thanks, I know that I can just import them through CDN but I am planning to distribute to desktop app that may not have internet connection, hence the need to have the font stored locally in the project

Comment: @Newbie You may find your answer  
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30442319/failed-to-decode-downloaded-font)

Comment: Thanks for trying, I checked out https://transfonter.org/ and was pretty hopeful but sadly I get the same error message as before

Comment: Awe yeah sorry I couldn't be of better help. Good luck!