# Plesk 12: Add new file types for nginx

Tags: nginx, plesk

My Plesk 12 uses Apache + nginx. Now I use webp and these are not served by nginx but Apache.

How can I add webp to the list of file types for nginx?

`/etc/nginx/mime.types` has webp in its image block tho:

```
types {
    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;
}
```

Edit: Serving the webp happens via rewrite rule jpg>webp in my Apache settings.

Comment: I would simply edit your nginx.conf: [extending default nginx mime.types file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16789494/extending-default-nginx-mime-types-file), then restart the services (or, better, reboot the Plesk VM).  See also https://wordpress.org/support/topic/rewrite-rules-for-nginx-1

Comment: Eh. Serving the webp happens via rewrite rule jpg>webp in my Apache settings.