# extending mime types in a Chef deployed Nginx server

Tags: nginx, mime-types, configuration-files

I'm looking to extend the mime types in my Nginx configuration.

I've learned that I could, in principle, either edit the mime.types file, or after including mime.types in the `http` block of the config you could follow `include mime.types` with a `types = {...}` to append more types a la [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20566966/1459594).

Since I'm setting up Nginx with Chef, I have a templated configuration in sites-enabled folder that's included into the Nginx config proper. I would prefer not to have to template the nginx config or mime.types file, so I'm hoping it's possible to get it in the sites-enabled config file.

In a similar spirit to the linked question above, could I include this in my sites-enabled file to get the same effect?

```
http {
    types {
        # here is additional types
    }
}
```

My working theory is that if blocks work as described in the link above, adding such a block would not overwrite the `http` block in the Nginx config, but would extend it as if I had added the `types` directly to the `http` block in `nginx.conf`.

Is this a valid strategy? Or am I overlooking something easier?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although not explicitly stated in the documentation, the `nginx` types directive appears to behave similarly to other directives with regard to inheritance.

The directive is inherited from the previous level if and only if there are no `type` directives defined on the current level.

The `types` directive may appear in the `http`, `server` or `location` block level.

To extend the mime types (rather than redefining them) to can add a `types` block with your additions in any file containing an `http`, `server` or `location` context.

But if you add a `types` block at the `server` or `location` level, you should also add another `include mime.types` statement at the same level, so as not to lose the system defaults.

In your sites-enabled files:

```
# (1)
server {
    # (2)
    location ... {
        # (3)
    }
}
```

If your sites-enabled file includes the `server { ... }` block definition, you might add a types block in position (1) which would augment the mime types already loaded by the main `nginx.conf` file.

However, if you added a types block in positions (2) or (3), you would also need to add an `include` statement to pull in the system types again:

```
server {
    include mime.types;
    types { ... }  
    ...
}
```

The `types` directive is [documented here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#types).

Comment: With my nginx 1.18.0 on Ubuntu 20.04 setup, putting `types` in `location` always invalidate the system defaults, regardless of whether `include mime.types` is specified or not. But putting custom `types` in `server` does successfully combine `mime.types` and my additional `types` properly.